# Get last part of URL path

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to get the last string after user with this request handler. Is it possible to do this without being hacky?

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/user/*")
 public class Student{
      @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String getUser(ModelMap model, /*, parameter that gets user id */) {
          // function that gets user id
          model.addAttribute("foo", "foo");
          return "bar";
      }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you've tried. SO is not a coding service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring has [@PathVariable](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) for the same.

```
@Controller
 public class Student{
      @RequestMapping("/user/{id}")
      public String getUser(ModelMap model, @PathVariable String id) {
          // function that gets user id
          model.addAttribute("foo", "foo");
          return "bar";
      }
}
```

Here I have assumed that user id is of String type, you may change the type of `id` as per your need.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@RequestParam` like this:

```
  @Controller
  public class Student{
  @RequestMapping(value="/user/{user_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getUser(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value="user_id") Long user_id){
      // function that gets user id
      model.addAttribute("foo", "foo");
      return "bar";
  }
}
```

Or use `@PathVariable`:

```
 @Controller
  public class Student{
  @RequestMapping(value="/user/{user_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getUser(ModelMap model, @PathVariable("user_id") Long user_id){
      // function that gets user id
      model.addAttribute("foo", "foo");
      return "bar";
  }
}
```